# Integrating SendGrid

Tags: smtp, sendgrid

I'm trying to integrate SendGrid in the MVC application. 
It is using the port 587. and SSL is enabled

```
Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
```

When I try to send an email, it is throwing : 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 159.122.224.196:587

```
 Message : Failure sending mail.
```

Also when I ping smtp.sendgrid.net, it is using the IP 159.122.224.197

Comment: Each of the SendGrid inbound geolocations has 2 IPs, so the `.196` vs `.197` is fine.
If you run a [manual telnet test](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200182038-Testing-your-connectivity-to-Sendgrid-s-SMTP-relay-using-Telnet), does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a firewall/antivirus application running on the machine that is blocking outgoing requests on port 587? If so, add a rule to allow outgoing requests on port 587.